# python save function variable to use in another function parameter

Tags: python

I have these two functions:

```py
def func1(my_list, test1, test2):
    my_list = [ {'name': 'Saeed', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'David', 'id': 2} ]


def func2(name):
    name[0]['id'] += 1
```

The `name[0]` is in fact `my_list[0]`, but I'm not sure how can I access it from the second function.

Comment: `print(func2(func1(...)))`

Comment: Why does `func1()` take `my_list` as a parameter if it immediately reassigns it?

Comment: @Barmar I edited the question. Using `par1='value'` was meaningless:( I edited to be more like the real function.

Comment: @Barmar my real world example is something like this, creates a list with the given name.

Comment: That change has no effect on the way you use the list. `func1` returns the list, you use the returned value when calling `func2`. This is basic programming in any language.

Comment: @Barmar aha, I remove the `return`. In the real function I don't have it.

Comment: you need to return the value or make it a global variable.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you're assigning the variable that was passed as a parameter. Are you expecting it to set the variable that you use in the call? Variables are passed by value, not by reference, in Python.

Comment: @Barmar I'm afraid I might not understand your comments fine (that's my fault unfortunately). I edited the question again.  Suppose I need to increment the `id` value by 1 each time when `func2` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the value from `func1()` so you can assign it to a variable. Then pass that variable to `func2()`.

```
def func1(my_list, test1, test2):
    my_list = [ {'name': 'Saeed', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'David', 'id': 2} ]
    return my_list

def func2(name):
    name[0]['id'] += 1

somevar = func1([], 1, 2)
func2(somevar)
func2(somevar)
print(somevar)
```

prints

```
[{'name': 'Saeed', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'David', 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand how to store the parameter `my_list` as a variable to use in another function? I didn't understand what `[]` means in your answer.

Comment: `[]` is an empty list. You need something for the `my_list` parameter of the function, even though you don't use it. You can put anything there.

Comment: I showed how to store it. Just assign the returned value to the variable. That works inside a function and also works at top level.

Comment: These are all very basic concepts of functions and variables. I can't be a substitute for a programming class.

Comment: Thanks, I know `[]` is an empty list, but I was not sure how it works in this concept. I use empty lists in other parts of my codes too. Thanks again, I'll test different ways to see that.

Comment: Your function requires 3 arguments, so I passed arbitrary values for them. It could have been `func1(1, 2, 3)`, it makes no difference.

Comment: I asked earlier why you have those parameters if you're not using them. You never answered.

Comment: It makes little sense to have `my_list` as a parameter and immediately reassign it in the function. It doesn't assign the caller's variable. If you pass a variable name as a string, it won't assign the variable with that name, that's not how variables work.

Comment: Got it. Regarding the parameters, I may forgot, pardon me. I didn't use in this example, but I have more than one parameters, so in order to be more like real, I did add them.

Comment: You can have parameters, but don't use the same name for a local variable inside the function.